# Removing final keyword from an existing method

Tags: java, final

Say, I have an existing code, which looks somewhat like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private AnotherClass obj;
    // ... (class implementation)
    public final getObj() { return obj; // It is this simple }
}
```

This class is implemented in a library, the versions of which are used by many different code bases.

I would like to remove the `final` from the `getObj()` method definition. I am aware of the fact that the method will no longer be [inlined](https://techblug.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/java-jit-compiler-inlining/).

What other possible side effects could removing the `final` keyword from `getObj()` cause to its existing users?

Comment: Only that it can now be overridden. Before you unfinal it, make sure you know why it was declared final. Will overriding it break some existing behaviour?

Comment: It's not true that the method will no longer be inlined. Modern JVMs can inline non-final methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Khelwood commented:

> When a method is declared with final keyword, it is called a final
>   method and it cannot be overridden and We must declare methods with
>   final keyword for which we required to follow the same implementation
>   throughout all the derived classes.

So, if you remove the `final` keyword any implementation class can override this method functionality (as @Khelwood suggestion it is better to know why it was declared as final before removing it).

Answer (score 0):

From your source:

> Methods that can be inlined include static, private or final methods
>   but also public methods if it can be determined that they are not
>   overridden.

Inlining is a process to minimize the overhead, and methods are inlined depending on the number of loops and calls.

The `final` keyword is used to define an entity that can only be assigned once. When used with methods they can not be overridden.

So removing it, means only you can assign that variable to another object, in case it is a method they can be overridden when the interface implemented or when the class inherited, no other side-effect!